# How to catch an Exception thrown by a custom IAuthorizationFilter in my custom ExceptionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception, custom-attributes, asp.net-mvc-custom-filter

I have a custom `ExceptionFilterAttribute` on my api controllers to handle exceptions, as well as a custom `IAuthorizationFilter` on the same controllers to handle custom security.

The `ExceptionFilterAttribute` catches exceptions and works fine for the most part, however it does **not** catch exceptions thrown from my `IAuthorizationFilter`. Those exceptions just get dumped back to the user raw without ever hitting the exception attribute.

Is there a way to do this? I attempted having both implement `IOrderedFilter` and specifying that the ExceptionFilterAttribute be processed first, but that didn't appear to change anything.

(this is .NET 6 fwiw)

This is the source of the controller all my controllers inherit:

```
[ExceptionHandling(Order = 1)]         // inherits ExceptionFilterAttribute
[EntityAuthorizationFilter(Order = 2)] // implements IAuthorizationFilter
public class ApiController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#exception-filters) Authorization filter

> - Run first
> - Determine whether the user is authorized for the request
> - Short-circuit the pipeline if the request is not authorized

And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#authorization-filters)

> - The exception will not be handled
> - Exception filters will not handle the exception

`IAuthorizationFilter` is executed before any other filter for every MVC request. So if it throws an exception or it's not authorized it will short-circuit the pipeline.

What you can try is to use exception handler middleware rather than an exception filter as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0)